# Get data from database in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla

How to extract data from single database table?

For example, i need data from table: categories, column: description with id 1 ?

Comment: i am trying to dig into joomla documentation, but nothing works for me, because i have not enough knowledge of php and sql so i need someones help :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you are trying to write a Joomla component, I recommend you to start learning writing your code with MVC architecture. Joomla Documentation on this subject is available [here](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Introduction). Anyhow, I'm gonna give you a simple but temporary solution and you have to rewrite it later using Joomla's MVC.

I presume that you want to select `column1` and `column2` data from your `#__example_table` and show then in a simple table.

First, you need to create a component with an empty view. You can use [this online tool](http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/) for creating a component at a glance; and of course it's free for creating components with empty views. After building, downloading and installing your component, let's call it `com_mycomponent`, there will be a folder called `com_mycomponent` in your `/components` folder. open it up and you'll see a `views` folder and inside it there's gonna be a folder for your view that I'm gonna call that `myview`.

In your view folder, there's a file called `view.html.php` which contains you view's class and also you can see a folder called `tmpl` which contains a `default.php` file for your view's template.

Now open `view.html.php` in an editor and create a public attribute called `$items` and `getData()` method after `display()` method like this:

```
<?php
class MycomponentViewMyview extends JView {

    .
    .
    .
    public $items;

    public function display($tpl = null) {
        .
        .
        .
        $this->items = $this->getData();

        parent::display($tpl);
    }

    public function getData() {
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select(array('column1', 'column2'));
        $query->from('#__example_table');
        $query->where('condition = 1');
        $query->order('id DESC');
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $results = $db->loadObjectList();
        if (!empty($results)) {
            return $results;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

In this example I've used Joomla's database API which are described [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase/2.5); and consider that dots means rest of the codes which you don't need to change.

Now open `/components/com_mycomponent/views/myview/tmpl/defailt.php` and delete everything here and write something like this:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die; // No direct access

if (count($this->items)) {
?>
<table style="width: 100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($this->items as $item) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $item->column1; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $item->column2; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php 
} else { 
    echo 'Sorry! No data found...';
}
```

I think the example is quite clear and there's no need of explanation, but I'm gonna give you a brief explanation about what's happening. First of all we created an method to get data from database and store them in a variable which is accessible from outside. Then we call that method from display method which is somehow the constructor of the view class. Then in the view's template I used a loop for the records stored in `$items` variable and show them in table rows.

- I tried to explain the solution in most simple possible way so that everyone could use it, and if it bothers you, I'm sorry.
- Feel free to ask question and correct me.

Comment: i have joomla component, it's name is joomshopping and i want to get components category description outside of category.

Maybe there is a php script which can get any information directly from database column?

Comment: I edited my answer and I think I gave you a complete guide for creating what you needed. I don't think I can explain the answer more simple. So if it answers your question or helps you through your work you can upvote my answer or mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thank you for your time and efforts. One more thing, i get this error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ../components/com_jshopping/templates/default/search/products.php on line 8

Comment: user `print_r($this->items)` and see if it contains anything. I wrote a if statement in my example to check the results. Your error says that you are trying to put an empty object or array in a loop. Maybe your query is not returning any results. You may show us your code so we can see what's wrong with it.